# How do I query available video memory using DirectX?

Tags: graphics, directx, windows

How do you query the amount of VRAM available when using DirectX?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to Game Coding Complete 3, there are a few ways:

- DX7's GetAvailableVidMem() - usually pretty good. Doesn't work too well on cards with shared memory.
- WMI (Windows Management Interface) has a similar result to the above.
- DxDiag uses both to give a better result.
- D3D9 has a GetAvailableTextureMemory() function, but can only be used on Windows Vista/7.

Look for a DX sample in March 08 or later SDK called 'VideoMemory'.

Comment: DX Sample for Video Memory is great -- should have found that before asking ;)

Comment: Considering how many computers will use shared memory, I would not recommend DX7's version. And how can the D3D9 version of this be only available on Vista+ ? D3D9 was there in XP...

Answer (score 5):

For DX9EX on Vista and later:

```
IDXGIDevice * pDXGIDevice;
hr = g_pd3dDevice->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIDevice), (void **)&pDXGIDevice);
IDXGIAdapter * pDXGIAdapter;
pDXGIDevice->GetAdapter(&pDXGIAdapter);
DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC adapterDesc;
pDXGIAdapter->GetDesc(&adapterDesc);
return adapterDesc.DedicatedVideoMemory;
```

(from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb174526(v=VS.85).aspx )

Comment: Not calling `Release()` on `pDXGIDevice` after a successful call to `QueryInterface()` will lead to a memory leak.